# Opencv Face morphing

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition, spline, morphing

I'm looking for a solution in order to perform a morph of a given face into another.
My deal is to match their features space perfectly in order to perform a better face recognition.

SIFT/SURF did't help me, and I've tried a [thin-plate spline processing](http://ipwithopencv.blogspot.ro/2010/01/thin-plate-spline-example.html) from landmarks, but the resulting face is too deformed (maybe I need more points).

I'd like to obtain something like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811997/opencv-suitable-implementation-for-thin-plate-spline-warping), does anybody know a way to obtain those points?

Comment: [this one](http://code.google.com/p/asmlib-opencv/) has a muct76 model

Comment: @berak, can I please ask why this package wasn't added to OpenCV?

Comment: hehe, no idea. actually, there's 3 or 4 more asm/aam attempts on github and code.google. the one above is just the only one using the c++ api.

Answer (score 5):

I recently wrote an article on Face Morphing using OpenCV ( C++ and Python )

http://www.learnopencv.com/face-morph-using-opencv-cpp-python/

I hope you find it useful. It uses dlib for facial feature detection, followed by delaunay triangulation, and finally morphing.

[image: Face Morphing Example]

Comment: I wann implement like this in Android but how i don't get it any way suggest me